# How to clip only intersection (not union) of clipping planes?

Tags: opengl, 3d, jogl

In OpenGL/JOGL, when using more than one clipping plane, the union of all clipping planes appears to be applied.  What I want is instead the **intersection** of all clipping planes to be applied.  Is this possible?  See the below simplified 2-D example.

[image]

Edit: An example of clipping by vertex shader (see comments below).
[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just use a fragment shader to compute if the pixel is in the region you want to render, and if not, just call `discard;`?

Comment: @fintelia Yes!  And that's exactly what my "test" is in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189491/how-to-pass-through-fixed-function-material-and-lighting-to-fragment-shader) you just answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-pass:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void scene()
{
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -2 * ar, 2 * ar, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable( GL_CLIP_PLANE0 );

    // -y plane
    GLdouble plane0[] = { -1, 0, 0, 0 };
    glClipPlane( GL_CLIP_PLANE0, plane0 );

    scene();

    // -x plane
    GLdouble plane1[] = { 0, -1, 0, 0 };
    glClipPlane( GL_CLIP_PLANE0, plane1 );

    scene();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Clipping" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `glClipPlane`, no. Vertices are clipped if they are outside the positive halfspace of *at least* one plane. Once that happens, it doesn't matter what any other plane may be.

However, you can get this effect (or almost any other effect) by writing appropriate values to [`gl_ClipDistance`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_ClipDistance.xml) in a vertex shader.

Any portion where the interpolated value that you write out is less than 0.0 ("negative halfspace") will be clipped, and you can write any value you like, e.g. the squared distance to a point, or the sum of distances to two planes, or anything else you calculate.

Comment: Is it possible to use `gl_ClipVertex` for the same purpose?  `gl_ClipDistance` is unavailable in my OpenGL 2.1 project.

Comment: Yes, but as explained in the question you linked to, it will be slightly more complicated. You need to supply 4-component points for the clip planes in the same coordinate system instead of just a single "distance value" which doesn't need to be in any particular coordinate system, since it's just a value that tells OpenGL "how close" you consider the point to being clipped.

Comment: I'm having trouble conceptually making the leap from `gl_ClipDistance` to `gl_ClipVertex`.  Every example I can find of `gl_ClipVertex` is simply `gl_ModelViewMatrix*gl_Vertex`.  It would be really helpful to see an example of using `gl_ClipVertex` to modify the clipping plane, in the same way that you described how `gl_ClipDistance` can be used.  I've tried setting `gl_ClipVertex` to all kinds of modified vertices in my vertex shader, but never see any change relative to what is clipped.  If you were able to post an example it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: `gl_ClipVertex` is a misnomer insofar as (although it _looks like_ a vertex, having 4 components) it's actually a plane equation, not a vertex. That is, a [normal plus a distance from the origin](http://www.songho.ca/math/plane/plane.html). `gl_ClipDistance` is the dot product of the plane and a vertex, or a notion of "how far the vertex is from being clipped", which is conceptually a lot easier. Setting `gl_ClipVertex` to actual vertices will likely not give a lot of sensible output since usually _w = 1.0_ -- so unless a vertex is very close to the origin you'll clip everything all the time.

Comment: With this approach, I am clipping vertices, not triangle primitives.  So I should not expect clean cut lines, correct?  Am I correct in assuming I would need to handle recalculating the split triangles myself (maybe in a geometry shader)?  Or am I missing an easy solution here?  (By the way, the issue I was having above was related to my fragment shader somehow hiding the effects of `gl_ClipVertex` -- I still have some GLSL learning to do obviously.)

Comment: Continued... I posted a screenshot of what I am seeing.  I am successfully clipping a single octant from a 3D model in a single pass.  However, the edges are jagged.  This makes sense to me in that I am clipping vertices -- and this clipping doesn't know anything about the triangle primitives.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: After some experimenting, I found that I can clip from the fragment shader, in a single pass, without the use of `gl_ClipVertex`.  In this case, the cuts are clean.  Still have [some issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189491/how-to-pass-through-fixed-function-material-and-lighting-to-fragment-shader), but it looks promising.