# How does gl_ClipVertex work relative to gl_ClipDistance?

Tags: opengl, 3d, clipping, vertex-shader

I was planning on using `gl_ClipDistance` in my vertex shader until I realized my project is OpenGL 2.1/GLSL 1.2 which means [`gl_ClipDistance`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_ClipDistance.xml) is not available.

`gl_ClipVertex` is the predecessor to `gl_ClipDistance` but I can find very little information about how it works and, especially relative to `gl_ClipDistance`, how it is used.

My goal is to [clip the intersection of clipping planes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901829/how-to-clip-only-intersection-not-union-of-clipping-planes) **without** the need for multiple rendering passes.  In the above referenced question, it was suggested that I use `gl_ClipDistance`.  Examples like [this one](http://github.prideout.net/clip-planes/) are clear to me, but I don't see how to apply it to `gl_ClipVertex`.

How can I use `gl_ClipVertex` for the same purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in doubt, you should always examine the formal GLSL specification. In particular, since this pre-declared variable was introduced in GLSL 1.3 you know (or should assume) that there will be a discussion of the deprecation of the old technique and the implementation of the new one.

In fact, there is if you look here:

#### [The OpenGL® Shading Language 1.3](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.30.10.pdf) - 7.1 Vertex Shader Special Variables - pp. 60-61

> The variable `gl_ClipVertex` is deprecated. It is available only in the vertex language and provides a place for vertex shaders to write the coordinate to be used with the user clipping planes. The user must ensure the clip vertex and user clipping planes are defined in the same coordinate space. User clip planes work properly only under linear transform. It is undefined what happens under non-linear transform.

Further investigation of the actual types used for both should also give a major hint as to the difference between the two:

```c
out float gl_ClipDistance[]; // may be written to
out vec4  gl_ClipVertex;     // may be written to, deprecated
```

You will notice that `gl_ClipVertex` is a full-blown positional (4 component) vector, where as `gl_ClipDistance[]` is simply an array of floating-point numbers. What you may not notice is that `gl_ClipDistance[]` is an input/output for geometry shaders and an input to fragment shaders, where as `gl_ClipVertex` only exists in vertex shaders.

The clip vertex is the position used for clipping, where as clip distance is the distance from each clipping plane (which you are allowed to calculate yourself). The ability to specify the distance arbitrarily for each clipping plane allows for non-linear transformations as discussed above, prior to this all you could do is set the location used to compute the distance from each clipping plane.

#### To put this all in perspective:

The calculation of clipping from the clip vertex used to occur as part of the fixed-function pipeline between vertex transformation and fragment shading. When GLSL 1.3 was introduced Shader Model 4.0 had already formally been defined by DX10 for a number of years, which exposed programmable primitive assembly and logically more flexible computation of clipping. We did not get geometry shaders until GLSL 1.5, but many other parts of Shader Model 4.0 were gradually introduced between 1.3 and 1.5